# switching between landscape and portrait mode makes some UI problems

Tags: android, user-interface, landscape

I have used 3 text views as footers in my application screen. When I used it as portrait then it fits the screen perfectly as shown below,

portrait Image

[image]

But when I turn it to landscape then it makes a huge gap between 2 text views (I and B).

landscape  Image

[image]

What is the reason for that and how can I overcome it? Any help will be highly appreciated.

.xml code used for this

```
<com.gamma.p.menu.QuickReturnListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/footerB"
    android:layout_width="106.5dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/textview_background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="8dip"
    android:paddingLeft="16dip"
    android:paddingRight="16dip"
    android:paddingTop="8dip"
    android:text="@string/footer3"
    android:textColor="@drawable/textview_font"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/footerI"
    android:layout_width="107dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/footerTop"
    android:background="@drawable/textview_background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="8dip"
    android:paddingLeft="16dip"
    android:paddingRight="16dip"
    android:paddingTop="8dip"
    android:text="@string/footer2"
    android:textColor="@drawable/textview_font"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/footerT"
    android:layout_width="106dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/textview_background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="8dip"
    android:paddingLeft="16dip"
    android:paddingRight="16dip"
    android:paddingTop="8dip"
    android:text="@string/footer1"
    android:textColor="@drawable/textview_font"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
```

**UPDATED**
I have changed my xml as shown below,

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/shareLILayout"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <lk.gamma.p.menu.QuickReturnListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/footerB"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/textview_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="8dip"
        android:paddingLeft="16dip"
        android:paddingRight="16dip"
        android:paddingTop="8dip"
        android:text="@string/footer3"
        android:textColor="@drawable/textview_font"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
    <!-- android:background="#D8000000" -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/footerI"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/footerTop"
        android:background="@drawable/textview_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="8dip"
        android:paddingLeft="16dip"
         android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingRight="16dip"
        android:paddingTop="8dip"
        android:text="@string/footer2"
        android:textColor="@drawable/textview_font"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/footerT"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/textview_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="8dip"
         android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="16dip"
        android:paddingRight="16dip"
        android:paddingTop="8dip"
        android:text="@string/footer1"
        android:textColor="@drawable/textview_font"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Now it looks like this,

[image]

Comment: make use of weights,it will help you out distribute layout uniformily

Comment: @Anuj I have RelativeLayout, and I got this error. Invalid layout param in a RelativeLayout: layout_weight

Comment: @modabeckham you can't use layout_weight in relativelayout it's for linearlayout only

Comment: @sur007 any idea how can I do this for RelativeLayout?

Comment: @modabeckham try using wrap_content instead of giving custom value

Comment: I have updated my question, do you mind taking a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `android:layout_width="match_parent"` into `android:layout_width="0dp"` inside `<lk.gamma.pizzakraft.menu.QuickReturnListView`. Then it will work for you.

**Complete code**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/shareLILayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <com.gamma.p.menu.QuickReturnListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/shareLILayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/footerB"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/textview_background"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="8dip"
                android:paddingLeft="16dip"
                android:paddingRight="16dip"
                android:paddingTop="8dip"
                android:text="@string/footer3"
                android:textColor="@drawable/textview_font"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/footerI"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/footerTop"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/textview_background"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="8dip"
                android:paddingLeft="16dip"
                android:paddingRight="16dip"
                android:paddingTop="8dip"
                android:text="@string/footer2"
                android:textColor="@drawable/textview_font"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/footerT"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/textview_background"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="8dip"
                android:paddingLeft="16dip"
                android:paddingRight="16dip"
                android:paddingTop="8dip"
                android:text="@string/footer1"
                android:textColor="@drawable/textview_font"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using fixed width values instead of letting the views to spread uniformly accross the desired screen space.

Instead of using widths use the same weight attribute for your footer views :

```
android:id="@+id/footerT"
android:layout_width="0"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

and do the same with the other footer views

**UPDATE:**

You need to wrap your views in a `LinearLayout` rather than `RelativeLayout` (as the latter does not respect the weight attribute)

Comment: I have RelativeLayout, and I got this error. Invalid layout param in a RelativeLayout: layout_weight

Comment: oh, it was not shown in your xml. RelativeLayout does not respect the weight attribute. You can use LinearLayout if its not a big change for you

Comment: I didn't know that layout will effect that, that is why I didn't show.

Comment: I have updated my question, do you mind taking a look at it. I have done it. Now when I run the application it doesn't show the textviews

Comment: I believe the com.gamma.p.menu.QuickReturnListView is in the way. try taking it out of the linearlayout and put it above (and wrap them all in another vertical linearlayout)

Comment: Even after that step still it shows the same. When I remove this ( com.gamma.p.menu.QuickReturnListView) then it showed perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Use Linear Layout with orientation as horizontal and then apply weights to each TextViews

```
<LinerLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/footerB"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
... 
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have updated my question, do you mind taking a look at it. I have done it. Now when I run the application it doesn't show the textviews

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are setting a specific `width` of your text boxes. When the orientation changes this does not allow it to adapt to the new screen size. Instead try setting the `layout_width` of each of your text boxes to `0dp` and like @anuj said make use of the `layout_weight` attribute by setting it to `1`.

Like so:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/footerB"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
... 
/>
```

Comment: I have RelativeLayout, and I got this error. Invalid layout param in a RelativeLayout: layout_weight

Comment: @modabeckham As @giorashc pointed out this only works with a `LinearLayout`. I'd suggest changing your `RelativeLayout` to a Horizontal `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Please do as follow if you are using Linearlayout. Let me know if it helps you

```
 <LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:orientation = "horizontal">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/footerB"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight= "1"
android:background="@drawable/textview_background"
android:gravity="center"
android:paddingBottom="8dip"
android:paddingLeft="16dip"
android:paddingRight="16dip"
android:paddingTop="8dip"
android:text="@string/footer3"
android:textColor="@drawable/textview_font"
android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/footerI"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight= "1"
android:background="@drawable/textview_background"
android:gravity="center"
android:paddingBottom="8dip"
android:paddingLeft="16dip"
android:paddingRight="16dip"
android:paddingTop="8dip"
android:text="@string/footer2"
android:textColor="@drawable/textview_font"
android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/footerT"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight= "1"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/textview_background"
android:gravity="center"
android:paddingBottom="8dip"
android:paddingLeft="16dip"
android:paddingRight="16dip"
android:paddingTop="8dip"
android:text="@string/footer1"
android:textColor="@drawable/textview_font"
android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If you need to use Relativelayout please use 
    "wrap_content" intead of giving custom width

Comment: I have updated my question, do you mind taking a look at it. I have done it. Now when I run the application it doesn't show the textviews